# How to create nomograms in R using subtracting equations

Tags: r, linear-regression, rms

I am using RStudio. I have created a nomogram using the nomogram function `nomogram` from the `rms` package. The following is the code:

```
library("rms")

n <- 100 
set.seed(17)

dat <- data.frame(BMI = abs(rnorm(n,30,0.5)),
                 Rib = abs(rnorm(n,10,0.1)),
                 LSM = abs(rnorm(n,36,2)))

dat <- upData(dat,
             labels=c(BMI='BMI', LTR = 'LTR', LSM='LSM'),
             units=c(BMI='kgm-2', LSM='mm', LTR='cm'),
             L = .045*(BMI-30) +
               (log(LSM - 10)-5.2),
             y_sample = ifelse(runif(n) < plogis(L), 1, 0))

dst <- datadist(dat)
options(datadist ="dst")

mmwm <- rms::lrm(y_sample ~ as.numeric(1.43*BMI) - LTR*(1.03*LSM) - 33.19,
                data=dat,  x=TRUE, y=TRUE)

mmwmngram <- nomogram(mmwm,  fun=plogis,
                     funlabel="dIMC-N Results")

plot(mmwmngram, xfrac=.45)
```

The Expected Result is to plot a nomogram that looks like this:
[image: This is an example of the results of the nomogram that I intend to create.]

The Error I am getting is provided is as shown below:

> Error in terms.formula(formula, data = data, specials = NULL) :
> invalid model formula in ExtractVars

I want to understand what code I need to write to use this equation  `(1.43*BMI) - LTR*(1.03*LSM) - 33.19` as it is.

Answer (score 0):

You used `LTR` in your formula, but it is not a column of `dat`. Therefore, the function can not extract this variable.
An R formula is of an abstract type, e.g. `y ~ x + b` representing any linear function and `y ~ x + b - 1` is any linear function without the bias. You can do sth. like this:

```
library("rms")

n <- 100
set.seed(17)

dat <- data.frame(
  BMI = abs(rnorm(n, 30, 0.5)),
  Rib = abs(rnorm(n, 10, 0.1)),
  LSM = abs(rnorm(n, 36, 2))
)

dat <- upData(dat,
  labels = c(BMI = "BMI", LTR = "LTR", LSM = "LSM"),
  units = c(BMI = "kgm-2", LSM = "mm", LTR = "cm"),
  L = .045 * (BMI - 30) +
    (log(LSM - 10) - 5.2),
  y_sample = ifelse(runif(n) < plogis(L), 1, 0)
)

dst <- datadist(dat)
options(datadist = "dst")

dat$BMI <- dat$BMI * 1.43

mmwm <- rms::lrm(y_sample ~ BMI + LSM + 1,
  data = dat, x = TRUE, y = TRUE
)

mmwmngram <- nomogram(mmwm,
  fun = plogis,
  funlabel = "dIMC-N Results"
)

plot(mmwmngram, xfrac = .45)
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Is there any other regression or equation I might use in the formula to cater for the negative equation? So that I can remove the bias.

Comment: I am still new to R and I am not getting a lot of insights from its documentation. I would also like to know how to set the ranges of the axis on the nomogram. For example in my case, ``` BMI = 5-30```. The BMI should be in that range and it should have increments of 5.

Comment: I think showing ranges in the nomogram does not make much sense, because its a representation of an unbounded linear model which accepts any value of BMI and predicts any real log odds value.